# Pushing notifications using getStream.io

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, android-notifications, feed, getstream-io

I want to push notification in `device` like FireBase notification. Is this possible through **GetStream.io APIs** ? Till now, I got the APIs related to `notification feeds and chats`, but I think these are for within/inside the application, not for `notifications on device`.

Please help and suggest whether I am able to push notification on mobile using GetStream.io ? Please clear my doubts regarding this.

Answer (score 3):

In short, for chat yes, for feeds no.

As you figure it out, feed notifications are in-app with [faye](https://faye.jcoglan.com/) or server side processing with SQS and webhooks. With server side, you can get your notification into your infrastructure, then you can take care of pushes to devices yourself.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Can you please provide any link or reference to implement pushing notifications of chats on mobile ?

Comment: https://getstream.io/chat/docs/push_introduction/?language=kotlin

Comment: @ferhatelmas can you please provide any **getstream.io link** or reference where it is mentioned that pushing notifications on mobile device is not provided by Getstream ?

Comment: here is the docs for feeds: https://getstream.io/docs/frontend_realtime/?language=kotlin

Comment: I am getting notification when I tried sending using CLI using this command stream chat:push:test. But when I send any message to other user, I dont get any notification. Please suggest if any other thing is needed to get chat notifications.

Comment: I would suggest creating a support ticket there you can provide more (private) details about your case and a push developer can help too.

Comment: @Curious were you able to resolve this issue? I am in the same boat and am stuck as getstream.io doesn't provide push notifications on mobile. I am surprised how any mature service can't provide such a must have functionality. –

Comment: @LearnToLive are you talking about feeds? Otherwise, chat provides push functionality.

Comment: @ferhat - I am talking about feeds. I am aware chat functionality has push notifications functionality. I am using activity feeds and want to show push notifications on mobile

Comment: @LearnToLive thanks, wanted to be sure. It might come in Q4 this year. Until that, you can get webhooks and do whatever you want via SNS, Firebase etc.

Comment: @ferhat, thanks for your response. Ok cool, will have to explore other options in that case.